# How to increment a null element in Groovy class

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception

```
CartEntry cartEntry = new CartEntry(quantity: null)
Integer quantity = 1
cartEntry?.quantity += quantity
```

I got java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot execute null+-1.

What is the best solution for this code?
I have:

> if (cartEntry?.quantity) {  cartEntry.quantity += quantity }

But, probably, it's not a Groovy way

Comment: if you have class, put this `if` into some method, then outer code will be minimalist like: `cartEntry?.addQuantity(5)`

Comment: Is null ever a valid quantity? If not, default the quantity property to zero in your CartEntry.

Comment: Yes, null is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a custom getter to your CartEntry class:

```
    Integer getQuantity() {
        quantity ?: 0
    }
```

So if quantity is null, it returns 0

Another would be to change your `+=` to

```
cartEntry.quantity = (cartEntry.quantity ?: 0) + quantity
```

Or as daggett says, add a method to your CartEntry class to increment quantity, and you can handle nulls in there

Comment: I decided to do: cartEntry?.quantity = (cartEntry?.quantity ?: 0) + quantity. Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `?` in `?.` as cart entry cannot be null